# PHP - Retrieving data from repeater fields in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom field in WordPress called `listing-two`. `listing-two` is a simple repeater field which allows you to add another item to a list.

Since a list may have x amount of listings, what is the best way to retrieve the data from that field? At the moment I have

```
'listingTwo'=> get_field('listing-two')
```

Which will not work since there are multiple fields?

I've seen the [AFC documentation](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/get-data-from-last-row-in-repeater/) to get an idea of how to get data, but none of them seem to work?

**Edit**:

I'm thinking the best way to go about this is via a for loop? I've tried the following, still not pulling anything through:

```
$textareaTwo = get_sub_field("listing-two");
if ($textareaTwo && count($textareaTwo)>0){
    foreach ($textareaTwo as $textareaTwos){
        $res = get_post($textareaTwos);
        echo'Test'.$res; 
    }    
}
```

**Repeater field structure:**

Field name: `listing-two` -> Has a sub field, with the field name `list_item`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if(get_field('listing_two')){
    $lists = get_field('listing_two');

    foreach($lists as $list){
         echo $list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

below is the code by which you can get all fields within `listing_two`

```
<?php if( have_rows('listing_two') ): 
      while( have_rows('listing_two') ): the_row(); 

        // vars
        $sub_field1 = get_sub_field('sub_field1');
        $sub_field2 = get_sub_field('sub_field2');
        $sub_field3 = get_sub_field('sub_field3');

        echo $sub_field1;
        echo $sub_field2;
        echo $sub_field3;

    endwhile; 
 endif; ?>
```

Comment: Is there an automated way to do this? I.e. I don't want to have to go into the back end all the time and assign a new variable for the next list element? I need an approach which automatically gets however much list elements there are in a list